# How to limit text input and count characters?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a text field and I want to limit the text that can be entered to 160 chars. Besides I need a counter to get the current text length.

I solved it using a **NSTimer**:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self 
         selector:@selector(countText) 
         userInfo:nil 
         repeats:YES];
```

And I display the length this way:

```
-(void)countText{
    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",
                                _textEditor.text.length];
}
```

This is not the best counter solution, because it depends on time and not on keyUp event. Is there a way to catch such an event and triggere a method?

The othere thing is, is it possible to block/limit text input, e.g. by providing a max length parameter on the text field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is (or should be) the correct version of the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
// "Length of existing text" - "Length of replaced text" + "Length of replacement text"
    NSInteger newTextLength = [aTextView.text length] - range.length + [text length];

    if (newTextLength > 160) {
        // don't allow change
        return NO;
    }
    countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", newTextLength];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It's a great answer for English-like(nontransfer) language, but for some languages which require spell-to-transfer, such as Japanese or Chinese, it counts incorrectly sometimes. For example, when you try to hit "に" on Japanese keyboard while spelling, it will count as 2 though normal it counts as 1. Also when you hit delete button while spelling, the count number just messed up...

Comment: great answer ... Thnks a lot

Comment: @RalphZhouYuan is correct. `-[UITextField addTarget:forEvent:]` is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

implement some of [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol methods

```
_textEditor.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    int len = [textField.text length];
    if( len + string.length > max || ){ return NO;}
    else{countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", len];
```

return YES;}
    }

Comment: This allows 161 characters in the text. Disables delete once those 161 are there. and it allows pasting of text longer than 160 characters. The problem is not that trivial.

Comment: Yes, the first problem is fixed. But you can't paste 20 characters over a selection of 150 characters ;-)

Comment: I just tried to point out the way, not to 100% solve the problem ;) See fluchtpunkt's answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if(textField.length < max){
    return NO;
}else return YES;
```

}

and set the max length and return NO.

Comment: textFieldShouldBeginEditing: will only prevent for start typing or not. threshold check has to be done every time the user inputs a key.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to limit the characters in UITextField, following code accepts 25 characters in UITextField.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
      {
            NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
            return (newLength > 25) ? NO : YES;
      }
```